# Code Interruption Error

Tags: vba, if-statement, while-loop, interruption

So the code I have below attempts to find WIP in column H. If we find WIP: copy 3 cells and make 10 replicas of them in the next column either in the same row or the next available row.

For some reason the code only runs the loop successfully for the first "WIP" value and then gives a code interruption error. Can someone see why this keeps happening?

Thank you, Ori

```
Sub Step1_update()

Dim dblSKU As Double
Dim strDesc As String
Dim strType As String
Dim BrowFin As Integer
Dim Browfin1 As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim Trowfin As Integer

Counter = 0

Worksheets("Final").Activate

Trowfin = 5
BrowFin = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'loop 1
Do While Trowfin < BrowFin

    'If 1 (set the 3 values)
    If Range("H" & Trowfin).Value = Range("H3").Value Then

         dblSKU = Range("F" & Trowfin).Value
         strDesc = Range("G" & Trowfin).Value
         strType = Range("H" & Trowfin).Value

         'Find the last used row in Col J
         Browfin1 = (ActiveSheet.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

         Counter = 0
         'paste values 15 times
         Do While Counter < 15

            'If 2
            If Browfin1 > (Trowfin + Counter) Then

                   Range("J" & Browfin1).Value = dblSKU
                   Range("K" & Browfin1).Value = strDesc
                   Range("L" & Browfin1).Value = strType


            ElseIf Browfin1 < (Trowfin + Counter) Then

                   Range("J" & (Trowfin + Counter)).Value = dblSKU
                   Range("K" & (Trowfin + Counter)).Value = strDesc
                   Range("L" & (Trowfin + Counter)).Value = strType

            Else

                   Range("J" & (Trowfin + Counter)).Value = dblSKU
                   Range("K" & (Trowfin + Counter)).Value = strDesc
                   Range("L" & (Trowfin + Counter)).Value = strType

            End If

        'Loop to paste the WIP 15 times
        Loop

             Trowfin = Trowfin + 1
             Counter = 0

    'If cell (H...) is not a WIP
    Else

        Trowfin = Trowfin + 1

    'If 1
    End If



'loop 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want the `Counter` to increment every time?  Should it be outside the `Else` right about the `Loop`?

Comment: I want the counter to increment 15 times so that I can paste the value 15 times, beside the value I search for. Although I need the trowfin to return to its original value after the loop is done. so that I can  continue searching the list . I have updated my work, tell me what you think.

Comment: It looks to me like you're begging for an infinite loop putting the `Counter` inside a conditional.  That is possibly what the code interruption is about unless you are manually breaking the code with the `BREAK` key.

Comment: How? I reset the counter so that every time I find my keyword in the list I copy it 15 times. or am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: Your edit removed the increment, but I would do `Range("L" & (Trowfin + Counter)).Value = strType : End If : Counter = Counter + 1: Loop`.  In that code, `:` represents a new line although it will technically run copied and pasted with the colon.  You need to increment *outside of the conditional* otherwise you run the risk that the counter **never** updates if that branch of code is not hit.

Comment: ElseIf Browfin1 < (Trowfin + Counter) Then
                    
                       Range("J" & (Trowfin + Counter)).Value = dblSKU
                       Range("K" & (Trowfin + Counter)).Value = strDesc
                       Range("L" & (Trowfin + Counter)).Value = strType
                    
                Else

Comment: ^ this is the step I keep getting the unexpected break on.

Answer (score 0):

Your previous code looked like:

```
  Else
    Range("J" & (Trowfin + Counter)).Value = dblSKU
    Range("K" & (Trowfin + Counter)).Value = strDesc
    Range("L" & (Trowfin + Counter)).Value = strType

    Counter = Counter + 1
  'If 2
  End If
Loop
```

You should do this instead:

```
  Else
    Range("J" & (Trowfin + Counter)).Value = dblSKU
    Range("K" & (Trowfin + Counter)).Value = strDesc
    Range("L" & (Trowfin + Counter)).Value = strType

  'If 2
  End If
  Counter = Counter + 1
Loop
```

Your current code has the increment inside the `Else` which means there is a chance that it will not be hit when the loop executes.  If this happens, it your loop will go on infinitely, crashing Excel or causing the code interruption.

If you want to loop based on a counter, you need to ensure that the counter will reach the exit condition in a non-infinite length of time.